# MySQL - How to know if the register is the first of an user

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to explain this.. I have a table with some records and I need to know if the register is the first of an user and show only if is the first to make a report of "new users"

I have a table of users: (basic data)

```
USERID - NAME - ADDRESS
------------------------
100 --- JOHN - XXXXXXXXX

200 --- MIKE - XXXXXXXXX

220 --- CARL - XXXXXXXXX
```

And a Table of ANSWERS (the table have more data - the answers for each activity - but is not importante for us)

```
ANSWERSID --- ACTID ----- USERID ---- START DATE ---- END DATE

10 ------------ 103 ------- 100 ------- 2015-05-10 ---- 2015-05-11
11 ------------ 101 ------- 100 ------- 2015-05-13 ---- 2015-05-15
12 ------------ 102 --------200 ------- 2016-05-22 ---- 2016-05-24
13 ------------ 101 --------220 ------- 2016-05-30 ---- 2016-05-31
14 ------------ 109 --------200 ------- 2016-06-10 ---- 2016-06-11
15 ------------ 19 ---------220 ------- 2016-06-11 ---- 2016-06-12
```

I have another table with each activity name

```
ACTID ---- ACT NAME
19 ------- LESSON A
100 ------ TEST A
101 ------ TEST B
102 ------ TEST C
103 ------ TEST D
109 ------ TEST M
```

(this table is not importante for the final result, but just to understand the data)

I have some "LESSONS" and "TESTS".

Lessons are ACTID between 1 and 99

Tests are ACTID >= 100

---

### MY PROBLEM:::

If the user complete a TEST and its your FIRST TEST I will send a "WELCOME KIT".

If the user complete a LESSON - he dont receive nothing..

Then, I will make a SEARCH on ANSWER TABLE to know new answers received between 2016-05-20 and today. (END TIME)

I receive this:

```
ANSWERSID --- ACTID ----- USERID ---- START DATE ---- END DATE

12 ------------ 102 --------200 ------- 2016-05-22 ---- 2016-05-24
13 ------------ 101 --------220 ------- 2016-05-30 ---- 2016-05-31
14 ------------ 109 --------100 ------- 2016-06-10 ---- 2016-06-11
15 ------------ 19 ---------220 ------- 2016-06-11 ---- 2016-06-12
```

but I need to know - with this - witch are the FIRST TEST for each user to send the WELCOME KIT

The correct TABLE IS:

```
ANSWERSID --- ACTID ----- USERID ---- START DATE ---- END DATE

    12 ------------ 102 --------200 ------- 2016-05-22 ---- 2016-05-24
    13 ------------ 101 --------220 ------- 2016-05-30 ---- 2016-05-31
```

Because ID 14 has USER 100 - and the FIRST TEST of user 100 was the ID 10.

and ID 15 is not a TEST - is a LESSON.

Then, of course, I need to Left Join / Inner Join this result with the USERS TABLE to receive the USER DATA - ORDER BY END DATE

```
USERID ----- USERNAME ---- ADDRESS --- ACTID ---- START DATE ---- END DATE

  200 --------- MIKE -------XXXXXXX ---102 ------- 2016-05-22 ---- 2016-05-24
  220-----------CARL --------XXXXXX ---101 ------- 2016-05-30 ---- 2016-05-31
```

*** IMPORTANT ***
Some END DATES are 0000-00-00 The user start to answer the activity but not ends.. In this case we dont sent to this user the Welcome Kit too..

Comment: You can add a `(select count(distinct answerid) from answertable where userid = xxx.userid and answerid < xxx.answerid) as howmanyactivitiesdididobeforethisone` somewhere. But without your actual code, I can't tell you where exactly, or if there is another or better way.

Comment: Hi @Solarflare tks a lot for your time and help! I don't understand what you need, because I dont have an actual code..I have some parts of the sql statament, but I cannot find the answer for my question with this..

Comment: Can a user take a test more than once?

Comment: @Daniel If you don't add the sql code you use, no proper table names or table descriptions, e.g. with the information if answerid is an autoincrement primary key or if all ids are tests, I cannot tell you exactly what the code is you need, so either provide your code, or be able to use my sql code at the right place. It will calc the number of answerids lower than the row-answerid. If it is 0, you have to send a welcome kit. You can add it as a column to the query that "will make a SEARCH on ANSWER TABLE..." (where xxx is the alias for your answerid-table) or use `where (my code) = 0` or both.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon tks for your time! Good Question  - NO. The user can take a test only 1 time. But the user can take ALL tests only 1 time.  - I have today 9 tests. (101, 102... 109) - All users can make all 9 tests, in any order, 109 first, 101 first..  only 101. only 109. only 101 and 109.. but when he takes your first test - I need to send him his welcome kit. Thats the problem, I can find in answers table for the same user many tests. The user can make all tests today, or 1 for month. Then, ADM will filter the tests for a period to send the kits..

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated sub query to get the first test for user based on answerid then decide if first test falls in date range. You haven't provided the data type for start and end date so I have assumed its date.

```
/*
DROP TABLE USERS;
DROP TABLE ANSWERS;
CREATE TABLE USERS (USERID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10), ADDRESS VARCHAR(20));
TRUNCATE TABLE USERS;
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES
(100, 'JOHN', 'XXXXXXXXX'),
(200, 'MIKE', 'XXXXXXXXX'),
(220, 'CARL', 'XXXXXXXXX'),
(230, 'DEKE', 'XXXXXXXXX')
;
CREATE Table ANSWERS (ANSWERID INT,ACTID INT,USERID INT,START_DATE DATE,END_DATE DATE);
TRUNCATE TABLE ANSWERS;
INSERT INTO ANSWERS VALUES
(10, 103 ,100, '2015-05-10', '2015-05-11'),
(11, 101 ,100, '2015-05-13', '2015-05-15'),
(12, 102 ,200, '2016-05-22', '2016-05-24'),
(13, 101 ,220, '2016-05-30', '2016-05-31'),
(14, 109 ,200, '2016-06-10', '2016-06-11'),
(15, 19 , 220, '2016-06-11', '2016-06-12'),
(16, 101 ,100, '2016-06-13', '2016-06-13'),
(17, 100 ,230, '2016-06-13', '0000-00-00')
;
*/

select  A1.*,U.NAME
from    ANSWERS A1
JOIN    USERS U ON U.USERID = A1.USERID
WHERE   A1.ANSWERID = (
                        SELECT MIN(A2.ANSWERID) FROM ANSWERS A2 WHERE A2.ACTID >= 100
                                AND A2.USERID = U.USERID
                        )
        AND A1.END_DATE IS NOT NULL
        AND A1.END_DATE <> '0000-00-00'
        AND A1.START_DATE >= CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE)
        AND A1.END_DATE   <= CAST('2016-05-31' AS DATE)
```